# Two instances of same class running via main - what is their associated unique identifier of each thread of main?

Tags: java

I am running the main method of a class twice, simultaneously via different executions and was looking at what would uniquely identify each one as it was running. It was simple to create something in myself:

```
String sid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

...but **is there anything inherent in each running execution** - part of the executing class - that I could use as a unique identifier.

We did a few approaches ourselves to see that we didn't know of something available we could use. We first wondered about using `Thread.currentThread().getName()` but both are *main*. I can't use `toString()` because there is no instance.

---

**Edit:** 
This class (GettingRollingClient) is what I'm running twice simultaneously, trying to differentiate between the two as they run... re-using a Java feature if I can:

```
java -cp "hazelcast-client-3.0.1.jar:hazelcast-3.0.1.jar:." GettingRollingClient
```

Comment: _I am running the main method of a class twice_ A method doesn't have an identifier. Are you running it in the same thread?

Comment: Sorry didn't know how to say - "running the same class twice simulataneously". Hope the edit helps

Comment: Try `Thread.currentThread().getId()` or `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to see if they work for you, or look further into the Thread class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: Each running instance has only one thread, so the thread id is 1 for each instance, and thread name is main for both

Comment: Ok @Crowie, this is what you want then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Comment: @Marcelo I really don't like that approach due to the platform dependency it creates.

Comment: @Marcelo Cheers mate I had a read. So there is a way but I agree with dbyrne. It seems to me that there is nothing simple in place because there isn't a simple, single, cut-and-dried answer to getting a PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach of generating a unique id yourself is the best idea.

The Java and JVM specifications do not define a natural unique identifier.  This means that any inherently pre-existing id will be specific to either the operating system or the JVM implementation.  This will tie your code to a specific platform and make it less portable.

Whether or not `UUID.randomUUID()` is the best way to generate an id yourself depends on your usecase.  One alternative would be to use a shared temp file with a counter to keep track of all the currently running processes.

Comment: In theory, since there are 2 different JVM processes, `UUID.randomUUID()` could return the same value for both runs.

Comment: @Marcelo There are easy ways to avoid that (highly unlikely) scenario such as using a temp file to store all the currently active process ids.

Comment: You are right, I think using a file would be the correct solution for the poster's problem, not really UUID generation and not really capturing JVMs process ID.

Comment: Wanted a solution that already exists because I suspected there was something I was missing. Looks to me, IMHO, like there is nothing because generating one is a better idea....