# How can I get the name of running Java VM?

Tags: java, jvm

How can I find the name of currently running java virtual machine name? I want to get it from java API.

Thanks

Comment: `ps aux | grep 'java'`

Comment: @JigarJoshi, looking for java API.

Comment: you can do it through java as well and write a little api

Comment: Better not to write your own if exist.

Comment: Simpler is `jps -lvm`

Comment: @PeterLawrey jps isn't available on all JVM distributions out-of-the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the process id of the current process you can do this.

[How can a Java program get its own process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id)

Answer (score 14):

Since you didn't really specify what you are looking for, take a look at these System Properties:

- `"java.vm.name"`
- `"java.home"`
- `"java.version"`
- `"java.vendor"`
- `"java.specification.vendor"`

Like this:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.specification.vendor"));
```

Comment: it is ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()

Answer (score 6):

There are two kind of JVM names namely:

1. Java Virtual Machine implementation name : Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
2. Java Virtual Machine specification vendor : Oracle Corporation

Type code in java program and see output:-

```
 System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine specification version  : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.version")); 
 System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine specification vendor : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.vendor"));
 System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine specification name : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.name"));
 System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine implementation version : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));
 System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor"));
 System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine implementation name : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));
```

refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/sysprop.htm

[see output of java -version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKiK0.jpg)

To know ur JVM vendor:
type `java -version` in cmd and see third line of it.

eg:

> C:\Users\jack>java -version
>
> java version "1.8.0_74"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2):

There is a variety of properties you can get with [`System.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29), `java.vm.name` seems like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getProperty("java.version")` should do the trick