# Java code to implement control break command

Tags: java, command-line, jvm, tomcat7

May be this question is too simple, but I am unable to find a solution anywhere.

I am running a webapp in Tomcat on JVM. I need to stop the JVM by invoking Control-Break. I need to do it from within the Java code. I don't know how to do it.

Can you please help me here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if it will kill the entire JVM, but `System.exit()` will kill the Tomcat server.

Comment: Other options include [JMX](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html)

Comment: Thanks! I know about system.exit(). I need to invoke in particular Ctrl_Break from within the Java code.

Comment: @Elliott How to use JMX to invoke Ctrl_Break?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't invoke Ctrl_Break like that, and how are you going to target the "correct" console to invoke Ctrl_Break on?

Comment: @Elliott I was thinking if I invoke the command from within the code, it will automatically target the containing JVM.

Answer (score 0):

you can always launch another process to do it for you, for example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -QUIT <pid>");
```

Comment: updated, changed to -QUIT, I think SIGINT is CTRL-C and QUIT is CTRL_BREAK, in any case you can use kill command to send those signals

Comment: to get the pid see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Comment: I ran the command, got the following exception: Executing kill -QUIT 7248
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "kill": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified