# java - which webserver is the application running on

Tags: java

I have a java app that can be run both on tomcat and jboss.

I need to do a "if condition" for performing certain tasks based on the webserver type.

How can I access this information?

I need to do that because I need to connect to the datasource, and I can get the Context in different ways based on the webserver:

```
try{
    String webserver = getWebServer();
    Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("myLog");
    if(webserver.equalsIgnoreCase("Jboss")){
        logger.severe("Webserver: " + webserver);
        Hashtable<String, String> ht= new Hashtable();
        ht.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        ht.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:1099");
        ht.put(InitialContext.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        InitialContext ic=new InitialContext(ht);
        if(ic!=null){
            logger.severe("success");/*I am getting success as output here*/
            DataSource ds=(DataSource)ic.lookup(getDatasource());
            /*this is where it's failing*/
            if(ds!=null){
                logger.severe("success1");
            }
            return ds.getConnection();
        }
        return null;
    }
    else{ //TOMCAT
        logger.severe("Webserver: " + webserver);
        // Obtain our environment naming context
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

        // Look up our data source
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup(getDatasource());

        // Allocate and use a connection from the pool
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Tomcat version doesn't work on jboss, and viceversa
Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: What sort of tasks do you want to do? It's unusual because the point of a war is that it can run in any appserver and shouldn't know about it.

Comment: I update the question to give more infos

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Comment: Do a request and read the header with some luck you get a hint which server is used. I understand that your app can work in any server and you propably don't have control over the server, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your application can run on Tomcat which is a simple servlet container then you might want to use [ServletContext#getServerInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServerInfo%28%29). to get Information about the environment your application is running inside.

Answer (score 2):

Quite unusual requirement, however can be achieved using System property. In server startup script pass System property in **JAVA_OPTS** like:

```
-Dserver=tomcat
```

Pass different values for different server and then You can read this system property by following code:

```
System.getProperty("server");
```

Comment: Isn't it better to put this parameter into the webdescriptor of the webapp ?

Comment: @PeterMmm: Usually yes, but not for this case, as the user wants to use same web app in two application servers.