# Java get PID from ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, pid, processbuilder

I start a Process with ProcessBuilder but i need to get the PID. (Process ID)

```java
List<String> bel = Arrays.asList(befehl.split(","));
ProcessBuilder bu2 = new ProcessBuilder(bel);
bu2.directory(new File("/home/cloud/" + modi + "/" + name));
Process p = bu2.start();
```

How can i dot that?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Comment: Even this one - http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid

Comment: You need it why?

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessHandle processHandle = p.toHandle();
System.out.printf("PID: %s%n", processHandle.pid());
```