# PID java application and kill

Tags: java, pid

I would like to **assign PID** to my java application (if it's possible), and kill every other javaw.exe.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM javaw.exe");
```

or PID

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID <ID>");
```

I know this will **kill all javaw.exe**, but I need my application still up and running.

It should kill specific java application, but they are having random PID's assign. I though the easiest way would be **close all java applications** running except mine.

Comment: Killing by PID is a requirement ? If not, open a socket and listening for a shutdown command is a much more cleaner solution.

Comment: Hello, no it's not. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: PIDs are given by kernel. Add a no-op identifier argument when launching applications "java -classpath ./lib com.package.MyApp key1=val1 key2=val2 processidenfier=abcxyz123". List processes with a full argument list, kill one by one with PID skipping an active java.exe process. Or use JNI/JNA to read current pid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Answer (score 0):

I've did it a little bit different. I've used "wmic", to list all the java process and PID at the end. I am taking the the last numbers and killing them.

```
wmic process where "name like '%javaw%'"
```