# IntelliJ idea: Show process id

Tags: java, c++, intellij-idea

I'm starting a java program from IntelliJ Idea which uses a `.dll` which is written by me in C++. After the startup of the application I can attach to the process using Microsoft Visual Studio (Debug / Attach to Process...) which allows me to debug the C++ part of the running application.

The name of the process is simply `java`. It is always a pain to select the right one from all the `java` processes. The simple *Task Manager* is not sufficient. The *Process Explorer* is good, but I still need to inspect multiple processes until I find the right one. It would be much easier for me if Idea would just tell the PID of the application it started.

Does Idea have such a feature?

(Win 7 64bit fresh @ 2017-04-19, Idea 2017.1.1)

Comment: Can you [get your own PID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35885/104891) inside your app and print it in the console/log?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can list all java processes with the `jps` utility (Can be executed from Idea terminal window) which makes it extremely easy to identify your process. Example scenario:

```
D:\projects\git\CENSORED>jps
12084
5476 WorkerMain
8772 WebSocketProxyMain
9444 Launcher
12920 RemoteMavenServer
13400 Bootstrap
7752 Jps
```

Comment: Hint: `jps -l` prints package names too which helps distinguishing if you see multiple `Main` classes, like `com.intellij.idea.Main`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a profiling application like "JProfiler" you can also very easily find the pid in the "quick attach" dialog.