# Will triggering a java program from another program use same JVM or will it use a different JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, runtime, exec

Will the below program use 2 different JVMs? One for main program and one for `Sample.jar` program?

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("will exec now");

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Sample.jar");
        while (p.isAlive()) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("still alive");
        }

        System.out.println("Done !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's launching a different process, a separate JVM.

Comment: As a side note, this code may lead to deadlocks, as `Runtime.exec` establishes pipes between the two processes, so when the subprocess expects input or produces more output than the pipe’s buffer can store, it will hang forever. If you do not want to handle the input & output of the subprocess, you can redirect it to the parent’s channels using `Process p = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "Sample.jar").inheritIO().start();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One for main program and one for Sample.jar program?

Yes, the `java` tool ([*nix docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html), [Windows docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)) launches a new instance of the JVM, completely unrelated to the running instance¹, just as though you'd run it directly, not via Java code.

In fact, the two JVM instances could even be different versions, if you have multiple installations on the machine (say, Java 9 and Java 10) and you're running this code in one of them (say, Java 9) but the `java` tool you're calling is for another (say, Java 10). But even if the same version, the two instances are completely unrelated to each other¹.

---

¹ (other than that the one is a parent process of the other)

Comment: Thanks!. Is there a way i can print the JVM information in the code to differentiate it is running in different JVM?

Comment: @user1 - You can get the process ID, which will be different between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id