# Send signals to child process in Java

Tags: java, signals

I'm making a Java app which requires me to be able to pause (and resume) a child process ran with `ProcessBuilder`. I thought I could do it by sending the signals `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` to the process, I googled it but I couldn't find anything regarding this.

How can I send a signal to a child process?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `kill`?

Comment: You can send data to the process via it's streams

Comment: Yes, I can send data but how about sending signals? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Define "signal"? How the process responds to the data is entirely dependent on that individual process

Comment: Do you not know about [process signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC))? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are opposed to kill, it is fairly straightforward.

```java
int child_pid = 12345;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -SIGSTOP " + Integer.toString(child_pid));
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to pause/resume the process, not kill it.

Comment: @mwarren despite the name, kill doesn't actually kill a process. It sends signals that you specify - which could be sigkill if you want it to.

Comment: How would I get the process PID from a `Process`?

Comment: @Fr3ddyDev `long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();` look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id) for more details

Comment: @ZacharyOldham I think you meant `childProcess.pid()`.  Killing the current (Java) process would not be a good idea.

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'pid()'` @ZacharyOldham @VGR

Comment: @Fr3ddyDev Process ID methods were added as of Java 9.  Is there a reason you’re using 8?