# How can i get process id of the same process from which i am running pgrep command?

Tags: java, macos, shell, java-8, terminal

I am trying to get ProcessId of the same process from which I am running the pgrep command. But the InputStream is returning null.

If we run command `pgrep terminal` from terminal in mac we cant get the processid of terminal. but if we run lsappinfo command in terminal and search for terminal it is there along with the processid.

I want to get processId of the same process from which I am running the command, Is there any other efficient way to get processId from process name like that of pgrep.

Comment: You mean you're trying to get your java program's pid?

Comment: yes, by calling pgrep from the same program using ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Then you might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35885/133203), particularly the part on how it's done since Java 9.

Comment: thanks, Federico but I need a solution in Java 8, and also i am not able to understand why can't we get the process id of the same process from it (For example : if you run `pgrep terminal` it will return null. even if that process has a pid, which we can get by `lsappinfo` and search terminal in it you can see the processid along with it).