# How to check process ID in linux?

Tags: java, linux, unix

Am hosting a jar file in GCP and everytime I make a change in the file ofcourse i would need to update the jar, but everytime I run the with the command `nohup java -jar java.jar &>> logy.log &` this run the file in background and gives a processes ID which is required to kill the process if I want to rerun the file when I make some changes. But once I restart the linux server I cannot find the process with the command   `bg` and I tried looking for several other commands on google but none seem to have help. I need a consitent way of killing the process rather than writting the process ID somewhere everytime I run the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a Java program get its own process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id)

Answer (score 1):

Can be use [process API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html), that added in Java 9. Process id can be obtain from:

```
long process_id = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, applications create a PID file that includes the PID and then kill with that info.
If you don't want to use this approach, maybe you can go with pkill.