# How can I get the PID of my Java application at runtime?

Tags: java, pid

I am running a simple Java application as follows:

```
class MyApp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the process ID (PID) of this application from inside my `main()` function so that I can save it to a file. How can I do that in a platform-independent way?

---

EDIT: The existing solutions on Stackoverflow are many years old and probably better solutions exist today. This is why I'm asking this question.

---

EDIT 2: I would prefer solutions that do NOT require Java 9.

Comment: which jdk version you use?

Comment: Better solutions do exist now. But they require java 9. The linked answer is the best you’ll get for java 8 - they haven’t been making lots of changes to it.

Comment: so you want a newer solution, but you don't want to use a newer jdk? what makes you think newer solutions will work if you don't update your jdk?

Comment: Also, depending on how you’re starting the program, it might be simpler to just write to the file as you start it. https://serverfault.com/questions/205498/how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process Something like that, but piped to a file.

Comment: Heres a similiar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Answer (score 3):

My operating environment is jdk6

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    System.out.print(name.split("@")[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RuntimeMXBean

```
RuntimeMXBean runtime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
long pid = runtime.getPid();
```

Comment: Is that only for Java 9? I can't see that method getPid()

Answer (score 0):

You can get PID by following

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getSystemProperties().get("PID")
```

Or

```
System.getProperty("PID");
```

[image]