# Get PID in logback log file

Tags: java, logback

When using logback outside of Spring-Boot, how can I get the ProcessID into the log file name?

In the `RollingFileAppender` I'd like to define:

```
<file>my-log-${PID}.log</file>
```

How can I get the `${PID}` set or is there a standard way of obtaining this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Learn how to get the own PID from inside the JVM - [How can a Java program get its own process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id)

   ```java
   ProcessHandle.current().pid()
   ```
2. Create a custom [PropertyDefiner](https://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/PropertyDefiner.html):

   ```java
   package com.example;
   import ch.qos.logback.core.PropertyDefinerBase;

   class PidPropertyDefiner extends PropertyDefinerBase {
     public String getPropertyValue() {
       return Long.toString(ProcessHandle.current().pid());
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use that property definer to inject a property into the logback:

   ```xml
    <define name="SELF_PID" class="com.example.PidPropertyDefiner" />
   ```

... or use the [`logback.groovy`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html) instead of `logback.xml`, there you can just access every bit of JVM directly.

Comment: Works great - thanks!  I also wasn't aware of logback.groovy :-)